# vsphere cloud provider for kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, provider, vsphere

Official documentation says that "standalone ESX was not supported" for vsphere cloud provider for kubernetes.
https://vmware.github.io/vsphere-storage-for-kubernetes/documentation/prerequisites.html

Could you please confirm it mean "1 esxi server without vcenter" or "1 esxi server with vcenter not clustered"?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Standalone ESXi can be defined as a single ESXi host without a vCenter Server